# Unable to remove a key from JSON Array in ES6

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a JS code in which I want to delete a specific key from JSON Array and my code is as below.

```js
var obj = [
    {
        XXX: "2",
        YYY: "3",
        ZZZ: "4"
    },
    {
        XXX: "5",
        YYY: "6",
        ZZZ: "7"
    },
    {
        XXX: "1",
        YYY: "2",
        ZZZ: "3"
    }
];

for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    delete obj[i].YYY
}


/*obj=obj.forEach(item =>{ return delete item.YYYY});*/

console.log(obj);
```

This code works fine and is giving me the result as expected, but, When I try to run it using `forEach` (commented lines), it is showing me undefined.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: forEach doesn't return a value so you will get undefined

Comment: thanks for this @AlexandroPalacios, so I think I can achieve my requirement using `map` rather than `forEach`. Is there any better way that you recommend ?

Comment: JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: @Rakesh yes you can using map. There is an answer below ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) doesn't return a value.

```js
var obj = [{
    XXX: "2",
    YYY: "3",
    ZZZ: "4"
  },
  {
    XXX: "5",
    YYY: "6",
    ZZZ: "7"
  },
  {
    XXX: "1",
    YYY: "2",
    ZZZ: "3"
  }
];



obj.forEach(item => delete item.YYY);

console.log(obj);
```

If you don't want to mutate the original array, you can use [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
var obj = [{
    XXX: "2",
    YYY: "3",
    ZZZ: "4"
  },
  {
    XXX: "5",
    YYY: "6",
    ZZZ: "7"
  },
  {
    XXX: "1",
    YYY: "2",
    ZZZ: "3"
  }
];



obj = obj.map(item => (delete item.YYY, item));

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: In your second example you are still mutating elements of the original array. Other answers do it correctly with `obj.map(({YYY, ...rest}) => rest)`

Answer (score 3):

Just remove the `obj =` part of your code. `forEach` always returns `undefined`. Since you're modifying the objects in your array and you want to replicate the `for` loop, `forEach` is fine, just don't reassign (and no need for `return` in the callback):

```
obj.forEach(item => { delete item.YYY; });
```

Live Example:

```js
var obj = [
    {
        XXX: "2",
        YYY: "3",
        ZZZ: "4"
    },
    {
        XXX: "5",
        YYY: "6",
        ZZZ: "7"
    },
    {
        XXX: "1",
        YYY: "2",
        ZZZ: "3"
    }
];

obj.forEach(item => { delete item.YYY; });

console.log(obj);
```

*(I removed the typo from the `forEach` code, you had an extra `Y`.)*

That said, there's nothing wrong with a `for` loop, or you could use a `for-of` loop:

```
for (const item of obj
    delete item.YYY;
}
```

Live Example:

```js
var obj = [
    {
        XXX: "2",
        YYY: "3",
        ZZZ: "4"
    },
    {
        XXX: "5",
        YYY: "6",
        ZZZ: "7"
    },
    {
        XXX: "1",
        YYY: "2",
        ZZZ: "3"
    }
];

for (const item of obj
    delete item.YYY;
}

console.log(obj);
```

Another alternative is to create a *new* array with *new* objects that don't have the `YYY`, via `map` and perhaps with destructuring:

```
obj = obj.map(({YYY, ...rest}) => rest);
```

Live Example:

```js
let obj = [
    {
        XXX: "2",
        YYY: "3",
        ZZZ: "4"
    },
    {
        XXX: "5",
        YYY: "6",
        ZZZ: "7"
    },
    {
        XXX: "1",
        YYY: "2",
        ZZZ: "3"
    }
];

obj = obj.map(({YYY, ...rest}) => rest);

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 2):

The [`Return value`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#return_value) value of [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) is `undefined`, the actual object is modified. Also, you can shorter your code by removing the curly braces (`{...}`) and `return` keyword:

```js
var obj = [
    {
        XXX: "2",
        YYY: "3",
        ZZZ: "4"
    },
    {
        XXX: "5",
        YYY: "6",
        ZZZ: "7"
    },
    {
        XXX: "1",
        YYY: "2",
        ZZZ: "3"
    }
];


obj.forEach(item => delete item.YYY);
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 2):

`forEach` doesn't return a value. Any value returned in the callback given to `forEach` is going nowhere.

Don't do this with `.map` either, because `delete` is *mutating* the objects. Your approach with a `for` loop is the right one.

It would be different if you would want to avoid object mutation, and would like to create entirely new objects and put those in a new array. In that case `.map()` is the way to go:

```js
let arr = [{XXX: "2",YYY: "3",ZZZ: "4"},{XXX: "5",YYY: "6",ZZZ: "7"},{XXX: "1",YYY: "2",ZZZ: "3"}];

let result = arr.map(({YYY, ...rest}) => rest);

console.log(result);
```

Here we isolate the `YYY` property with destructuring notation, collecting the other properties in `rest`, which is then the object you really want to have.

Answer (score 0):

use obj.map instead of obj.forEach